# Customised maven deployable (war with some dependencies removed)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-2

I have a multi module web app building with maven. We build the war as per normal and deploy and run on developer machines and local test servers using tomcat.

Then we want to deploy the application to the cloud. To do this we create a special version of  tomcat which has all the libraries preloaded and a special version of the war which only has our code. Point here is tomcat is preloaded on the cloud server, the war is uploaded each time it is changed. Currently we are having to manually remove the dependencies from the built war.

What is the best way for maven to do this? Should I build a custom packaging type or maybe run some post build plugin to remove these wars? Or something else? I think the best way to activate this custom build is via a profile. I did try and remove these dependencies by setting them to `scope = provided` in the new profile but the transitive dependencies still made it into the war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude *all* dependencies, you can use the war plugin's `packagingExcludes` to do so:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            ...
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Specify this plugin inside a profile to only perform it for production.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is perfect. I can filter out/in dependencies. This is what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using profile in maven. As you said it is not working, I can think of you configure something wrong. Try something like:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <!-- active by default, turn off when on prod -->
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <!-- include this in dev, not in prod -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.company</groupId>
          <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Then in command line, `mvn package -P !dev` to deactivate `dev` profile so that not include the jars.

Make sure `com.company:xzy` is not included in `<project><dependencies></dependencies></project>`.